# How do I write \nsupseteq with kpfonts?

Tags: kpfonts

```
\documentclass[9pt, a4paper]{extarticle}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, total={170mm,257mm}, left=20mm, top=20mm,}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb} 

\usepackage{kpfonts}

\begin{document}

$\nsupseteq \, \nsubseteq$

\end{document}
```

If I try to run this (in ShareLaTeX), then the symbol for `\nsupseteq` would look weird, but `\nsubseteq` wouldn't.

I found out the problem is the package `kpfonts`. But I do like the font.

How do I fix this?

Comment: I filed a bug report to Christophe Caignaert.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a bug in the font `jkpsyb`; in slot `0x2B` there's the same symbol as in slot `0x29`, instead of the analog of the symbol in slot `0x2A`. Here's the relevant part of the font table:

[image]

The bottom line shows the problem.

Workaround:

```
\documentclass[9pt, a4paper]{extarticle}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, total={170mm,257mm}, left=20mm, top=20mm,}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{kpfonts}
\renewcommand{\nsupseteq}{\not\mathrel{}\supseteq}
\renewcommand{\nsubseteq}{\not\mathrel{}\subseteq}

\begin{document}

$\nsupseteq \, \nsubseteq$

\end{document}
```

This changes both symbols to use `\not` for the negation; only changing the faulty one would make them dissimilar.

[image]

Why the strange `\mathrel{}`? Because the `kpfonts` package tries to outsmart: it redefines `\not` to look forward in order to see whether a symbol that can be negated follows. So with `\not\supseteq` we would end with an infinite loop, because it would be translated into `\nsupseteq` and this into `\not\supseteq`…

Since neither `\notmathrel` not `\nmathrel` is defined, no substitution is performed. Consecutive relation atoms get no space between them, so the effect of `\not\mathrel{}<relation>` is the same as `\not<relation>`.

Note that you should not load `amssymb` together with `kpfonts`.

Comment: Regarding amssymb  isn't either enough to just load kpfonts last? This is yet another bug in kpfonts. IMO there is also a bug in the size of `\big(`, the jump compared to ( is too large.

Comment: @daleif That might depend on other factors; a similar issue happens with `fourier`.